# how to show attribute value for sorting in products list in magento

Tags: attributes, products, sorting

I have a attribute color which have value , red, green, blue, white, black and i want to show all these color value in product list page for sorting just like name and position.

Is there anyway to show these color value in product sorting in place of name and position.

Comment: I want to show these option in toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes->Open color attribute**

[image]

And also set category **"Is Anchor" to yes**

From Catalog->Manage Categories->Edit Category->Go to tab Display Settings-> Set Is Anchor to Yes

Comment: I want to use these color options in toolbar not layered navigation

Answer (score 1):

Set '**Used for sorting in Product listing**' to '***Yes***' on attribute frontend properties.

Comment: i already set that but i want attribute value for sorting not attribute name